# flutter firestore access a document with a parameter disregarding upper- and lowercase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to access a document with a specific parameter disregarding caps?

The code with my ref to firestore:

```
 var ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users') .where('email', isEqualTo: email);
```

When I search for `email@email.com` I want to access document if the email is equal to `Email@email.com` or `email@Email.com` etc.
Is this possible in any way other way than calling multiple times with all possible combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Firebase Firestore` does not offer developers case-insensitive queries. If you need to use a query like in your option, you have to make the client code use that for all queries.

For instance, you could store all strings as lowercase in the database, then require your client code to convert all strings to lowercase before querying.

Comment: Great thanks. That was the exact workaround solution I came to, with storing all as lowercase, seems to perfectly solve my problem.